# SharepointOnline property GetAuthenticationCookie

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm have a script that was provided to me, to assist with some Office 365 / SharePoint online tasks.

The script (below) is meant to connect to our SharePoint tenant, but is coming to a halt when a call is made to using the `GetAuthenticationCookie($URL)` property/object of the user credentials:

```
$AdminURI = "https://tennant-admin.sharepoint.com"
$MySitesUrl="https://tennant-my.sharepoint.com"

$AdminAccount = "adminuser@domain.com"
$AdminPass = ""

# Convert the Password to a secure string, zero out the cleartext 
$sstr = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $AdminPass -AsPlainText -Force
$AdminPass = ""

# Take the AdminAccount and the AdminAccount password, and create a credential
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($AdminAccount, $sstr)

# Add the path of the User Profile Service to the SPO admin URL, then create a new webservice proxy to access it
$proxyaddr = "$AdminURI/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?wsdl"
$UserProfileService= New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $proxyaddr -UseDefaultCredential False
$UserProfileService.Credentials = $creds

# Take care of auth cookies
$strAuthCookie = $creds.GetAuthenticationCookie($AdminURI)
```

When I step through the code, it returns an error at the last line (above), which is shown below:

```
Exception calling "GetAuthenticationCookie" with "1" argument(s): "The sign-in name or password does not 
match one in the Microsoft account system."
At line:1 char:1
+ $strAuthCookie = $creds.GetAuthenticationCookie($AdminURI)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdcrlException
```

The error appears to state that the sign-in name or password is not valid - yet it is, as I can login with the same details (clearly removed from above) via the Microsoft web-portals.

I thought at first this might be a proxy issue - which I've ruled out. 
I tried from a PC directly connected to the Internet, same error.

So I'm guessing whatever format the data is in, when getting called/posted isn't in the correct format.

When I do a get member of `$creds.GetAuthenticationCookie` I get the following back:

```
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSMethod

Name                MemberType Definition                                                                  
----                ---------- ----------                                                                  
Copy                Method     System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo Copy()                            
Equals              Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                              
GetHashCode         Method     int GetHashCode()                                                           
GetType             Method     type GetType()                                                              
Invoke              Method     System.Object Invoke(Params System.Object[] arguments)                      
ToString            Method     string ToString()                                                           
IsInstance          Property   bool IsInstance {get;}                                                      
MemberType          Property   System.Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes MemberType {get;}                
Name                Property   string Name {get;}                                                          
OverloadDefinitions Property   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[string] OverloadDefinitions {get;}
TypeNameOfValue     Property   string TypeNameOfValue {get;}                                               
Value               Property   System.Object Value {get;set;}
```

I've drawn a blank with searching for others with the same issue.

My other thought was that I do have multi-factor auth enabled for my account, which I think is possibly the case. Would I need to create an application password and use this instead. This being the case, how does one get PowerShell whitelisted from MFA?

Answer (score 0):

The following example demonstrates how to authenticate Web Services in Office365/SharePoint Online in PowerShell

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function GetAuthCookies([Uri]$WebUri,[string]$UserName, [string]$Password)
{
    $SecuredPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecuredPassword)
    $authCookie = $credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie($WebUri)
    $cookieContainer = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer
    $cookieContainer.SetCookies($webUri, $authCookie)
    return $cookieContainer
}


#Usage
$Url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com"
$UserName = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = "password"


$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "$Url/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx" -UseDefaultCredential False
$proxy.CookieContainer = GetAuthCookies -WebUri $Url -UserName $UserName  -Password $Password

$profile = $proxy.GetUserProfileByName($accountName)
```